# Wordpress and directory issues

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am having a few problems with WordPress and my directories. Basically I have my Wordpress site hosted on root but every time I try and access another directory e.g

mysite.com/Moodle/

it takes me to the 404 for the WordPress site rather than the files in the other directory.
I have read that .htaccess is the key. But I am presented with these problems:

**[Solved]: Turns out my old host 123reg hasn't finished updating the nameservers which cause the problems.**

Comment: The first thing you can do is to show hidden file with your ftp client.

Comment: As it stands it won't let me connect via ftp client. Only file manager in Cpanel. (I assume I should contact the host about that)

Comment: Please post your sollution as an answer, not as an edit to the original question. This way the Q&A form of the site remains, and it is easier for a next visitor to follow the thoughtprocess of the trouble. Be as clear and detailed as possible/needed in your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my old host 123reg hasn't finished updating the nameservers which cause the problems.